# Data Exchange Framework Resolve Sitecore Item from bucket?

Tags: data-exchange-framework

Sitecore 9.0.2, DEF 2.0.1

I have a pipeline that imports data and creates/updates items in a folder. Unfortunately, the data set that will be used is quite large, so we need to add these items to a bucket, instead.

When I change the item container to a bucket, however, it no longer finds existing items, presumably because the `InProcItemModelRepository.GetQueryableForSearch()` method looks for direct children, instead of all descendants of the root item:

**(decompiled code from `Sitecore.DataExchange.Local.dll`):**

```
// ...
if (settings.RootItemIds.Any<Guid>())
{
    Expression<Func<FullTextSearchResultItem, bool>> expression1 = PredicateBuilder.True<FullTextSearchResultItem>();
    foreach (Guid rootItemId in settings.RootItemIds)
    {
        ID d1 = new ID(rootItemId);
        expression1 = expression1.Or<FullTextSearchResultItem>((FullTextSearchResultItem i) => i.Parent == d1);
    }
    queryable = queryable.Where<FullTextSearchResultItem>(expression1);
}
// ...
```

Does anyone know of a way to configure the pipeline step to look for all descendants instead of a child?

Answer (score 3):

This is a know bug.

Sitecore support created a patch for it. https://sitecore.box.com/s/d1b9g17oquhbl8hg1tvpyywj0bsytrfi

To install it please follow next steps:

For all Sitecore instances in the solution:

1. Make a backup of the files mentioned in Contents section and listed in the installation instruction (if any).
2. Copy the contents of the Website folder from the archive to the Website folder of your Sitecore solution, overwrite existing files if any conflicts occur.
3. For all your processor step items that use processor type:
   "Sitecore.DataExchange.Providers.Sc.Processors.PipelineSteps.ResolveSitecoreItemStepProcessor, Sitecore.DataExchange.Providers.Sc"
   Change it to the following:
   Sitecore.Support.DataExchange.Providers.Sc.Processors.PipelineSteps.ResolveSitecoreItemStepProcessorSitecore, Sitecore.Support.235033
4. (Optional) Copy the Sitecore.Support.235033-2.0.1.0.zip archive into the $(data)/patches folder permanently.

More information you can find here: https://github.com/sitecoresupport/Sitecore.Support.235033/releases

Comment: I actually ended up implementing my own because I didn't want to update the existing Sitecore provider's template. (I added [an answer in the other question](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/18096/342).)